# How can I know which admin delete pub/sub subscription in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

There are times when we lost pub/sub topics or subscription or service accounts. We would like to know who did this. Is there any admin activity logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout this link: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/audit-logging
You can find which kind of audit logs are available for pub sub.
With this audit logs you can understand, in depth, who made what, when.